# FireFox 3.6 insists on automatic update, but fails to start - How can I disable auto udpate?

Tags: firefox, browser, auto-updates

I am using FoxTester to run firefox 3.6 to test my development site on non-html5 browsers.

It used to work fine for week until suddenly when try to launch 3.6 it will try to install an update (presumably firefox 16), but fails. As a result I cannot launch 3.6 at all.

How do I stop firefox from running auto-update?

I had a look at the [mozilla support site here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version#Configuring_update_options) and seen many other forums suggesting the same. The thing is though that I cannot get to those settings as I cannot launch firefox 3.6
to disable auto-update as the auto-update prevents me from launching it.

Is there a configuration file where I can disable auto update or a launch parameter?

Comment: Why don't you simply install an even earlier version?  You could always compile Firefox 3.6 yourself and disable the check.

Comment: @Ramhound wow! `compile firefox`, that's overkill

Comment: @Ramhound well I was already struggling to find a version as old as 3.6 and I don't think what compiling would be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Look in your profile directory.
  (Where your profile directory is, depends on your operating system and version. Note: it might be in a hidden directory).
- Open the file `prefs.js`
- If it has a line saying
  `user_pref("app.update.enabled", true);`
  change the true to false.
- Otherwise, add a new line saying
  `user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);`
  Note: the lines probably need to be in alphabetical order, so make sure you insert it in the right position.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, it is a last resort. Normally it's not recommended to edit the prefs.js directly (since you can change all the prefs by going to `about:config`) but if you can't start up the browser because of a setting that needs to change, you can do that.